# ErrorError : Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease

Tags: android, gradle, apk

```html
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.jlubecki.soundcloud:soundcloud-api:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.vpaliyX:SoundCloud-API:v1.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.hendraanggrian:socialview-commons:0.15.0'
    compile 'com.hendraanggrian:socialview-core:0.15.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.brucetoo.pickview:library:1.2.3'
    compile 'com.vimeo.networking:vimeo-networking:1.1.0'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'mx.openpay:openpay-api-client:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.github.tabassumLatif:ShimmerRecyclerView:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.jaedongchicken:ytplayer:1.4.2'
    compile 'com.github.Alelak:Soundroid:1.1'
    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile project(path: ':openpayandroid')
}
```

Comment: Hola amigo, cual es la pregunta? . Te invito a realizar el [tour] para que sepas el funcionamiento básico del sitio, además revisa [ask],Saludos!

Comment: Sin saber la pregunta presupongo que el problema que estas teniendo seguramente se debe a que has sobrepasado los 65K métodos, podrías optimizar las librerías excluyendo "duplicados" o si no te es posible, habilita multidex